# how could I make this query working " SELECT ... AS week_day... week_day WHERE COUNT(username) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM ..."

Tags: mysql, sql

sample of users table is:

```
 select * from users limit 10;
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+
| id | username              | created_at          |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Kenton_Kirlin         | 2017-02-16 18:22:11 |
|  2 | Andre_Purdy85         | 2017-04-02 17:11:21 |
|  3 | Harley_Lind18         | 2017-02-21 11:12:33 |
|  4 | Arely_Bogan63         | 2016-08-13 01:28:43 |
|  5 | Aniya_Hackett         | 2016-12-07 01:04:39 |
|  6 | Travon.Waters         | 2017-04-30 13:26:14 |
|  7 | Kasandra_Homenick     | 2016-12-12 06:50:08 |
|  8 | Tabitha_Schamberger11 | 2016-08-20 02:19:46 |
|  9 | Gus93                 | 2016-06-24 19:36:31 |
| 10 | Presley_McClure       | 2016-08-07 16:25:49 |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the following query works fine:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%W') AS week_day, COUNT(username) AS counts FROM users 
GROUP BY week_day ORDER BY counts DESC;
+-----------+--------+
| week_day  | counts |
+-----------+--------+
| Sunday    |     16 |
| Thursday  |     16 |
| Friday    |     15 |
| Monday    |     14 |
| Tuesday   |     14 |
| Wednesday |     13 |
| Saturday  |     12 |
+-----------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the following 2nd query works fine:

```
SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( u.created_at, '%W') AS week_day, COUNT(u.username) AS counts FROM users AS u GROUP BY week_day ORDER BY counts) AS x;
+---------------+
| MAX(x.counts) |
+---------------+
|            16 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT this query does not work!!!!

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%W') AS week_day, COUNT(username) AS counts FROM users GROUP BY week_day WHERE COUNT(username) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( u.created_at, '%W') AS week_da
y, COUNT(u.username) AS counts FROM users AS u GROUP BY week_day ORDER BY counts) AS x);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE COUNT(username) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts) FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( u.create' at line 1
```

I have tried many alternatives but it still does not work one of those is 
where 2=......
where counts = ......

HOW Can I fix this?
What I need to do is to dynamically generate the day names with maximum users created on those days something like

```
+----------+--------+
| week_day | counts |
+----------+--------+
| Sunday   |     16 |
| Thursday |     16 |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: trying to get the day names with maximum users created at that day

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the simplest way to do what you want, but your syntax problem is not using a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%W') AS week_day, COUNT(username) AS counts
FROM users
GROUP BY week_day 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(x.counts)
                   FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( u.created_at, '%W') AS week_da
y, COUNT(u.username) AS counts 
                         FROM users u
                         GROUP BY week_day 
                        ) x
                  );
```

Comment: your solution works like charm. Yet, I am curios about what is the simplest way to get same results?

Comment: @MohammedMahmoud . . . Ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the results you want.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the wished for results